# How can I stream a local screen capture remotely ( I own a web server )?

Tags: linux, video, streaming, home-server

I have a VPS Debian server and I would like to stream my screen capture I have locally, so friends could watch what I'm viewing basically. How can I do this? I suspect I would need to have VLC sort of feed my web server, where my web server is setup so there's a streaming server installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using either [RecordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) or [xvidcap](http://xvidcap.sourceforge.ne) as they both have live encoding features, and pair that up with VLC for streaming.

I haven't tried that yet myself, so let me know how well that works.

Comment: How exactly does VLC's streaming work though? I'm on a public IP from the Comcast ISP, so would it stream from my public comcast IP? Is that what someone else would have to visit to see my stream? Or do I have to setup my Debian Server if I wanted to share it from there with something like Darwin Server?

Comment: yes, it would stream from your public comcast ip address.  It's actually got a really easy to use wizard to set it up.  http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html